# NSDateFormatter dateFromString return null

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdateformatter

I want to get NSDate from NSString. My code:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [NSDateFormatter new];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"2016-05-05 09:29:31"];
NSLog(@"date %@",date);
```

And I see in console:

```
date (null)
```

What is wrong with my date format? Thank you.

Comment: are you sure `05-05` is `MM-dd` or `dd-MM`

Comment: Hi, this code does not have any problem i am getting the object of NSDate.

Comment: i got date  : 2016-05-11 17:20:06.498 StackLearn[11440:173878] date 2016-05-05 03:59:31 +0000

Comment: There is nothing wrong in code i think. It should not return null!!!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code is correct.

If the device is set to AM/PM time and requested string format is set to @"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" dateFromString will return nil. Try setting the locale like :

```
[dateFormatter setLocale:[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"]];
```

Comment: This is it! Thank you!

Comment: @EugeneTrapeznikov - Great!!

Answer (score 1):

I tried your question

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [NSDateFormatter new];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"2016-05-05 09:29:31"];
NSLog(@"newDate :  %@",date);
```

I got the output like

[image]

Answer (score 1):

try this code

```
NSString *dateString = @"05-05-2016 09:29:31";
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

// if format doesn't match you'll get nil from your string, so be careful

[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss"];
NSDate *dateFromString = [[NSDate alloc] init];

dateFromString = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
```

Comment: The format not matching the input was my issue. I resolved it by first setting the formatter's format to match the expected input, creating the date, then changing the formatter's format to the desired output and calling [dateFormatter stringFromDate:dateString]

Answer (score 1):

You can also use my code for getting NSDate from NSString for any kind of format you want.

Below is my code :

```
- (NSDate *)dateFromString:(NSString *)stringDate withFormat:(NSString *)format {
    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

    formatter.dateFormat = format;

    NSDate *dateFromString = [formatter dateFromString:stringDate];

    return dateFromString; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below code ..

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"];
NSString *date_time  =  [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
```

Hope this is useful